# There exists a differentiable function for which $f'\left(x\right)=\begin{cases} \frac{\cos x-1}{x^{2}} & x\ne0\\ 1 & x=0 \end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometry, solution-verification

Prove or disprove: There exists a differentiable function for which $$f'\left(x\right)=\begin{cases} \frac{\cos x-1}{x^{2}} & x\ne0\\ 1 & x=0 \end{cases}$$

**My way**:

False. Assume towards a contradiction that there exists such function.

Then we have:

$$f'\left(0\right)=1$$ $$f'\left(2\pi\right)=0$$

By Darboux's theorem, there exists $$0<c<2\pi$$ such that:
$$f'\left(c\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$
Thus:
$$f'\left(c\right)=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\cos c-1}{c^{2}}\Rightarrow$$ $$\cos c=1+\frac{c^{2}}{2}>1$$
**Contradiction!**

.

My question is - would it been easier to disprove by integrating and trying to find the original function?

Even if not, could I see the shortest method on this case please?

Thank you.

Comment: What you have nicely side steps around finding the actual value of $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$, as many other proofs would do! A slight rearrangment of essentially the same proof could note that $f'(x)<0$ whenever $x \neq 0$, so that $f'(c)=1/2$ is impossible.

Comment: I see that now, great thinking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a clever argument. I had a different application of Darboux's Theorem in mind. By Taylor polynomial considerations (or, if you insist, l'Hôpital's rule), you see that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f'(x)=-1/2$. But Darboux's Theorem tells you that $f'$ cannot have a jump discontinuity, so no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Interesting way of thinking, thank you for sharing it!

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks perfectly fine, great job!

The function given for $f'(x)$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=0$. There's a theorem in analysis stating that the derivative of a differentiable function can't have removable or jump discontinuities. But if you look at a typical proof of this theorem, it's pretty much the same argument as your solution here — such a proof would either refer to Darboux's Theorem or would reproduce the Intermediate Value Theorem argument that lies behind Darboux's Theorem.

So short of stating that "there's a theorem for this", your solution is the best approach, imho.

Comment: I already gave this answer.

Comment: Thank you sir !

Answer (score 1):

I think another way of doing it would be showing that the function you have stated has a discontinuinty at $x=0$ and show this by evaluating:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}$$
from above and below if you want to be thorough and then use the fact that no differentiable function exists where its differential has a discontinuity

Comment: What you just said is very false. The derivative of a differentiable function can very well be discontinuous (but defined everywhere). People upvoting you should not.

Comment: @TedShifrin : thanks for pointing this out. People should take care when voting. On the other hand the answer may be fixed by changing "a discontinuity" to "a jump discontinuity" (at the end).